pymysql.err.IntegrityError - 1062, "Duplicate entry - Unique constraint
Below is my update query :
update table_name
set Name = concat('zzzz', Name)
where ID = 100

The table has unique constraint on ID and Name -
UNIQUE KEY `UK_table_name` (`ID`,`Name`)

ID and Name are not primary keys
I have checked values in Name column for ID = 100. All values are distinct.
Why am I getting (1062, "Duplicate entry '100-zzztable_name.Name' for key 'UK_table_name'")
I was expecting all values in Name column to be updated.
Sample Data : Not actual data
select ID, Name
from table_name 
where ID = 100

ID Name
100 book
100 ball
100 sky
100 sun


The update processes rows one at a time. While adding zzzz to one of the rows it ends up being the same as another row that hasn't been processed yet.

You have many rows with id = 100 to update? In that case you will get a duplicate error if name starts out the same for all of them. Please add sample data and expected outcome as text

@P.Salmon Yes, multiple rows exist for the same id = 100

The order that the rows are processed matters. Suppose you start with the following table
ID  Name
100 A
100 zzzzA

If it updates the first row first, there are temporarily two rows with name=zzzzA, causing a duplicate key error. If it updates the second row first, you get name=zzzzzzzzzA before replacing A with zzzzA, so the duplication is avoided.
You can solve this by telling it the order to do the updates:
update table_name
set Name = concat('zzzz', Name)
where ID = 100
ORDER BY LENGTH(Name) DESC

Doing the longer names first ensures that you will not get any temporary duplicates.

Thank you. I will try this. What about the case when no value starts with zzz ? This is my use case right now.

If that's really the case I don't see how this could happen. Can you post sample data that reproduces the problem?

I created a dummy table and my update query worked as expected.

The error message implies that you already  had a row with name=zzztable_name.Name

It looks like you may have accidentally created a row containing the column name as a literal value, when you were intending to concatenate.

I got it to work. At SQL level my update statement works as expected. The issue was in syntax for update using SQL Alchemy.
Incorrect query :
stmt = (update(table_name)
.where(table_name.ID == input_id,
.values(Name=f'zzz{table_name.Name}))
Correct query :
stmt = (update(table_name)
.where(table_name.ID == input_id,
.values(Name='zzz' + table_name.Name))
